# How to use the subprocess.check_output comand correctly

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to execute the the shell script `generateLicense.sh` with different arguments. I do it like that:

```
License = subprocess.check_output(['./generateLicense.sh -firstargument 1 -secondargument 2 -thirdargument 3'])
```

The shell script is in the same folder as the file that starts the shell script but i always get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) the way you are trying to, each command has to be an item in the list you are passing. So, what you should have is:

```
License = subprocess.check_output(['./generateLicense.sh', '-firstargument', '1', '-secondargument', '2', '-thirdargument', '3'])
```

Here is a replication of your problem using a different command to showcase what is happening when you pass a multi-argument command as a single string in the list being passed to `check_output`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["ls -a"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Doing this in Python 3 you will actually get something more coherent:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls -a'
```

Comment: License = subprocess.check_output(['./generateLicense.sh', '-firstargument', '1', '-secondargument', '2', '-thirdargument', '3']) does still throw the same error